# NuGet version coflict with SignalR and Owin

Tags: c#, nuget, signalr, owin

I’m trying to setup up a selfhosted SignalR & WebAPI project with owin, following this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2prTfk0n9x0 ) but I quickly ran into issues. My project creates a class library which is loaded by my main application.

As shown in the video I've installed three NuGet Packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
- Microsoft.Owin.Cors

While loading my library an exception occurs telling me, that the package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (2.4.1.0) tries to load Microsoft.Owin Version 2.1.0.0 but it found a differed version (4.0.1).

I've added:

```xml
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

To both `app.config` files, the one of my library project and the one of my main application but with no effect.
I'm not very familiar with `nuget` so I ran out of ideas how to solve this problem.

This is the full (german) Exception text + additional information:

```
    Die Datei oder Assembly \"Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)

    === Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
    LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\n (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/projects/MyApp/bin/Debug/
    LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
    Aufruf von Assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
    ===
    LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
    LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\\projects\\MyApp\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.exe.Config
    LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
    LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config wird verwendet.
    LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/projects/MyApp/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Owin.DLL.
    WRN: Der Vergleich des Assemblynamens führte zum Konflikt: Hauptversion.
    ERR: Das Setup der Assembly konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden (hr = 0x80131040). Die Suche wurde beendet.
```

/Edit as result of Matěj Štágl's answer:

I forgot to mention, that I tried to downgrade already, but it just forced me do downgrade more and more, because all dependencies must be downgraded, too.

I just did it again to give an idea of it:

- Downgraded to Microsoft.Owin 2.1.0 makes Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core to require Microsoft.Owin 2.0.2.0.
- This downgade forces also one of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core the new Version requires Microsoft.Owin 2.0.1.0.
- A new downgrade makes System.Web.Http to require System.Net.Http.Formatting in version 5.0.0.0.
- A downgrade of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client makes System.Net.Http.Formatting ask for Newtonsoft.Json in version 4.5.0.0. This version is not offered by NuGet and Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core want’s version 4.5.11 of Newtonsoft.Json at the same time.

Comment: Please try to reinstall your all packages by Update-Package –reinstall. This will reinstall you all packages with the original version and dependencies with the latest versions.

Comment: @habib: It looks like this will take no effect. If I call it at the end of the downgrade path I will still receive the Newtonsoft exception. When I use git to switch to a higher version state I will receive the error of that state. Even after deleting “packages” an “obj” folder.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to install the version of `owin` SignalR calls for. Open nuget packages manager, select installed tab, select Microsoft.Owin and in the right panel, under version dropdown select 2.1:

[image]

Alternatively you can do the same via Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin -Version 2.1.0.0
```

Comment: Tanks for the answer. I already tried that, without success. I added that information at the question.